# How do I specify database model in a serpy serializer?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models,

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

I am trying to learn serializing using serpy.

I wrote two serializers, but I am not sure how to mention the model. I wrote a django rest framework serializer, as follows,

```
class PublicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = 'title',

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    publications = PublicationSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is the serializers that I wrote for using with Serpy.

```
class PublicationSerializer(serpy.Serializer):

    title = serpy.Field()

class ArticleSerializer(serpy.Serializer):
    headline = serpy.Field()
    publications = PublicationSerializer()
```

I dont know where should I mention the model,

I would like to be able to serialize a queryset, say

```
Article.objects.all()
```

**what changes must be made to use it with Django Rest Framework?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently don't need to specify an associated model for the `serpy` serializer. Passing your Django objects to the appropriate `serpy` serializer class should suffice. Or not?

```
articles = Article.objects.all()

articles_serialized = ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True).data
```

Comment: in other words with Serpy you have to manually add the fields you want from the model to your serializer class, rather than having the serializer fields added automatically from the model definition with DRF